# Should I use li-ion CR1220 cell or a different chemical type?

Tags: coin-cell

I have bought an RTC module that needs a CR1220 coin cell, but is supplied without one. Should I use a Li-ion cell or a different chemical type, and what advantages or differences are there between them? I cannot find any guidance at all so far on-line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CR1220 is a lithium/manganese dioxide cell at 3V. It's a non-rechargeable coin cell battery with about 40mAh capacity.

A lithium ion cell is a 3.7V rechargeable cell with a massive range of capacities.

Can your RTC operate on up to 3.85V without issue? Do you require increased capacity or rechargeability?

I would just go with the CR1220. You'll get a higher energy density from the Li/MnO\$_2\$ and the proper voltage.

Comment: Thank you Samuel for that prompt and very helpful answer.

Comment: Comment only: LiIon can have terminal voltage up to 4.2V max when fully charged  (or in some cases almpost 4.3V)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thanks, I was under the impression that was the maximum charging voltage, not the maximum open terminal voltage.

Comment: @Samuel Unlike many other chemistries, with LiIon the max charging and max O/C terminal voltage are the same. This can be considered as 4.2V per cell for most purposes. In most applications they use employ a CCCV charging system - first CC (constant current) at the max allowed charging current or less until the max allowed voltage is reached (usually 4.2V) and then in CV = constant voltage mode. In CV mode V= 4.2V say and Ichg is set by the battery chemistry - and drops non linearly with time. From about the end of the CC stage on, the battery Voc will be 4.2V even though not fully charged.